# My custom LoginFilter is authenticated and it calls the login success callback, why is it not executed to the Controller layer?

Tags: rest, spring-security, jwt

this is my custom `LoginFilter`:

```
public class LoginFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    public LoginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        // 需要是 POST 请求
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        // 获得 session 中的 验证码值
        String sessionVerifyCode = (String) session.getAttribute("verify_code");
        // 判断请求格式是否是 JSON
        if (request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ) || request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)) {
            Map<String, String> loginData = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                loginData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                String code = loginData.get("code");
                checkVerifyCode(sessionVerifyCode, code);
            }
            String username = loginData.get(getUsernameParameter());
            String password = loginData.get(getPasswordParameter());
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("用户名不能为空");
            }
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("密码不能为空");
            }
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(username, password);
//            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
            setDetails(request, authRequest);
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } else {
            checkVerifyCode(sessionVerifyCode, request.getParameter("code"));
            return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        }
    }

    private void checkVerifyCode(String sessionVerifyCode, String code) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("验证码不能为空!");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionVerifyCode)) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("请重新申请验证码!");
        }
        if (!sessionVerifyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("验证码错误!");
        }
    }
}

java
```

this is spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(IgnoreUrlsConfig.class)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private IgnoreUrlsConfig ignoreUrlsConfig;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RestfulAccessDeniedHandler restfulAccessDeniedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DynamicSecurityService dynamicSecurityService;
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DynamicSecurityFilter dynamicSecurityFilter;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests();
        //不需要保护的资源路径允许访问
        for (String url : ignoreUrlsConfig.getUrls()) {
            registry.antMatchers(url).permitAll();
        }
        //允许跨域请求的OPTIONS请求
        registry.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                .permitAll();
        // 任何请求需要身份认证
        registry.and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler((req, resp, authentication) -> {
                    resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
                    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                    out.write("注销成功");
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                })
                // 关闭跨站请求防护及不使用session
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // 自定义权限拒绝处理类
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(restfulAccessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .apply(MyCustomDsl.customDsl())
                // 自定义权限拦截器JWT过滤器
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);



        //有动态权限配置时添加动态权限校验过滤器
        if(dynamicSecurityService!=null){
            registry.and().addFilterBefore(dynamicSecurityFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
        }
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
java
```

The `MyCustomDsl.customDsl()` is:

```
public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(loginFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
//        http.addFilter(loginFilter(authenticationManager));
    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }

    LoginFilter loginFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        LoginFilter loginFilter = new LoginFilter(authenticationManager);
        loginFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/sso/login");
        loginFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        loginFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        loginFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        loginFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        return loginFilter;
    }
}
java
```

The Controller is:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sso/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CommonResult login(@RequestBody LoginParam loginParam){
        String token = umsAdminService.login(loginParam.getUsername(), loginParam.getPassword());
        if(token == null){
            return CommonResult.validateFailed("用户名或密码有误");
        }
        Map<String, String> tokenMap = new HashMap<>();
        tokenMap.put("token", token);
        tokenMap.put("tokenHead", tokenHead);
        return CommonResult.success(tokenMap);
    }
java
```

I expected it to execute the Controller to generate the token and return it, but the postman test results in printing the callback function for my successful authentication.

This is my MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        out.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(principal));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
java
```

When I postman test the interface /sso/login, the result printed is my success callback function above.

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized the logic to finally meet my expectations, the logic is: the front-end submits an interface /sso/login, which has not been authenticated, the interface will accept the front-end parameters (username & password) to produce a token to return to the front-end.
I defined the JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter for token authentication, the front-end interface has not been authenticated to let it go to the Controller's interface /sso/login for authentication.
Next I give up using LoginFilter this filter, but use to use inheritance DaoAuthenticationProvider this class to carry out the verify code authentication.